What does Judaism say about opposites / polarities?
I asked this question on the Philosophy StackExchange, What philosophies don't say things boil down to polarities (opposites)?, as some belief systems have deep belief that everything is on a spectrum of polarity/opposites.
What does Judaism say about polarities/opposites? Does everything have an opposite? If so, how (I have several examples in my linked question, of what I think cannot be polarities).

There are extremes, and there is the middle, which by definition cannot have an opposite. This seems basic common sense, and accords with Maimonides' instruction to take the middle path.

Sometimes the notions we consider opposites are not opposites in Judaism, but rather different traits, although mutually exclusive. Hatred is not negative love, for example. Faith in G-d is not negative of belief in idols.

גַּ֣ם אֶת־זֶ֤ה לְעֻמַּת־זֶה֙ עָשָׂ֣ה הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים

@YDJ Of course true faith in G-d excludes idols. That is the basic interpretation of the first two of  the  Ten Commandments. See Eliyahu at Har Hacarmel.

@N.T. while it is true, true faith also includes doing many other things, which absence of believe in idols does not mandate nor can imply.

@YDJ "Hatred is not negative love", oh wow nobody's really said that to me before, but it's kind of true.

@LancePollard are you asking in general about opposites? If you are looking for specifics e.g. opposites in terms of character traits etc. there is a lot to say.

@YDJ Then you should say it is "more than". And hate is the opposite of love, as said in Ecclesiastes (Ch. 3 iirc). You are trying to hard to be capital-P profound.
